# Linearity and Monotonicity of Lebesgue Integration of bounded functions

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am going through the proof in Royden's Real Analysis of the following proposition:

Let f and g be be bounded measurable functions on a set of finite
measure E. Then for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$\int_{E}(\alpha f+\beta g)=\alpha\int_{E}f+\beta\int_{E}g$

The proof starts by establishing linearity for $\beta=0$, which I could follow without problems. It then goes into establishing linearity for $\alpha=\beta=1$. It goes like this:
Let $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ be simple functions for which $f\leq\psi_{1}$ and $g\leq\psi_{2}$ on E. Then $\psi_{1}+\psi_{2}$ is a simple funciton and $f+g\leq\psi_{1}+\psi_{2}$ on E. Hence, since $\int_{E}(f+g)$ is equal to the Upper Lebesgue integral of f+g over E, by the linearity of integration for simple functions, $\int_{E}(f+g)\leq\int_{E}(\psi_{1}+\psi_{2})=\int_{E}\psi_{1}+\int_{E}\psi_{2}$

To which point I can follow and understand, however the next paragraph is the one I am having difficulties understanding:

The greatest lower bound for the sums of integrals on the right-hand side, as $\psi_{1}$ and $\psi_{2}$ vary among simple functions for which $f\leq\psi_{1}$ and $g\leq\psi_{2}$, equals $\int_{E}f+\int_{E}g$. These inequalities tell us that $\int_{E}(f+g)$ is a lower bound for these sums. Therefore, $\int_{E}(f+g)\leq\int_{E}f+\int_{E}g$

Specifically, how are we moving from

$inf\{\psi_{1}:\psi_{1}\mbox{ simple and }f\leq\psi_{1}\} = \int_{E}f$

$inf\{\psi_{2}:\psi_{2}\mbox{ simple and }g\leq\psi_{2}\} = \int_{E}g$

To the result?

Comment: $$\int f +\int g = \inf_{f\leq \psi_1}\int \psi_1 +\inf_{g\leq \psi_2} \int \psi_2 = \inf_{\psi_{1} \geq f, \psi_{2} \geq g}( \int\psi_1  +\int \psi_2) \geq \int (f+g)$$

Comment: btw, royden really defines the integral as an infimum of simple functions? thats seems really weird

Comment: no, he defines a function being integrable over E whenever the infimum of all simple functions over f and the sup of all simple functions under f are equal.